# Password incorrect after upgrade to .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm using asp.net 4.6.1 using native UserManager to handle Register/Login flow. After upgraded to .net core 1.1, it appears that the hash algorithm has changed so users could not login using the old password.
For example, the password "P@ssword123" was hashed as "ABiX7922FWETSxMXAlvD91GI1HwQSmb4ArreR+wa3R9bbz13/ITuwxshQjnIg30Zsw==" but the new hashed value that generated by .net core is "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAECMDFIuBWc4dTtEuLL6RUfszQLjnWzluDNUFNuCPWBqlLzgVx0ASLWvBUTuShLnulQ=="

does anyone have any idea to change hash algorithm of .net core so that it could be backward compability with old asp.net 4.6 framework?

Comment: What hash algoritm? (SHA1? MD5? SHA-256?)

Comment: hmm... I havent tested yet. But, I only need a way to customize hash algorihm of UserManager, so that I could test it out to know which one is correct. :(

Comment: Just found out there is a place to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333399/asp-net-core-identity-extending-password-hasher/37349142.  
With this, I could at least test out which algorithm suite the old framework.
Thanks guys.